# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pye57 with Python 3.11.3

Tags: python, pip, windows-11, open3d

I tried to pip install pye57 for editing Point Clouds in python.
I always get an error in my windows 11 console.
Anyone had the same problem and can help?

Windows 11
Visual Studio Code
python 3.11.3
pye57 (ERROR)
open3d (ERROR)

### Thank you guys very much!

```
PS C: PLACEHOLDER> python -m pip install pye57
Collecting pye57
  Using cached pye57-0.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:PLACEHOLDER\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from pye57) (1.24.2)
Collecting pyquaternion (from pye57)
  Using cached pyquaternion-0.9.9-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pye57
  Building wheel for pye57 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pye57 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\e57.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\exception.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\scan_header.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      copying src\pye57\__version__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pye57
      running egg_info
      writing src\pye57.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\pye57.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\pye57.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\pye57.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\pye57.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\pye57.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      error: Error: setup script specifies an absolute path:

          C:PLACEHOLDER\Local\Temp\pip-install-koqdxluf\pye57_dd22e940f58f48559c3ec9348b31363e\libE57Format\src\BlobNodeImpl.cpp

      setup() arguments must *always* be /-separated paths relative to the
      setup.py directory, *never* absolute paths.

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pye57
Failed to build pye57
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pye57, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install the package and an error accured. I tried to check for a newer version of pye57 without success.

Comment: This is an issue with the package, see also [on github](https://github.com/davidcaron/pye57/issues/38)

Answer (score 1):

A while since you posted but just faced the same issue, see below:

In conda, create and activate new environment

- Follow 'Buidling from source' from: https://github.com/davidcaron/pye57
  cd pye57
- go and see in this directory and look for `setup.py`
- change include_package_data to False
- then: `python -m pip install`

Don't forget the dependencies.